# Which API level should i download to develop an android app

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am new for android and going to download new android SDK so which level should i choose 8 or newest 21?

Comment: I'd go with API Level 10, 19, and 21, personally. API Level 8 is such a chore, people should just buy a new phone already.

Comment: @DerGolem technically they should do it for the updates to the OS and the new functionality. Not upgrading is only giving themselves a disservice. API Level 8 doesn't even support OpenGL ES 2.0 yet. It has issues with SSL connections (although that might be level 7)... supporting them isn't necessarily worth it.

Comment: @DerGolem well to me this whole discussion is similar to how "but we might need to develop for IE6 because there are still people who are not willing to switch to Chrome *AND* aren't willing to switch to Windows 7 or above even though XP is deprecated and no longer supported". But you're right, there are still people with API-Level 7 and 8 phones. It's up to you (and the requestor of the app you are developing) to decide whether the extra hassle with supporting obsolete versions is worth it for you. If you do have the extra time to debug their quirks, then by all means support them. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should download API 21 obviously and set `Minimum SDK` as per your requirement. That way you will be able to run your app from early Froyo(If you keep `Minimum SDK` as 8) phones to Lolipop ones.

So when you start with Android Development you will find configuration options in `AndroidManifest.xml` like `MinimumSDK` version(minimum version of android you want to support), `TargetSDK`(max version of OS u want to support) version and `CompileSDK`(usually equal to target SDk version) version.

Comment: Not really necessary. You may download API-8 too and use the app in any upwards release

Comment: How ? @waqaslam , API 8 supports 21?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam If you've released an app using API-8, it will work for 8 and above

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam because of backward compatibility and forward compatible support libraries

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)
You should download API v21 and use min level 15 or 16 because versions below are already not so much distributed (API v10 = 7.4%, API v15 = 6.4%, API v16 = 18%).