# compile for SDK21 android app

Tags: android, sdk

My app works fine with targetSdkversion = 25 and compileSdkversion = 25

Now I need to make it work for targetSdkversion as 21. The app is failing with an error app stopped working.

Do I need to change any tool version or any other parameters?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "MY.APP.NAME"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 11
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Comment: @Sara  Thank you but after reading this I find myself more confused. Does that mean, targetversion has nothing to do with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share the error log you are getting , because as stated in the link, you should compile your application against the lowest possible version of the platform that your application can support.
[Should compile sdk be lower than target sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295866/should-compile-sdk-be-lower-than-target-sdk)